# VBA conditional and replace

Tags: vba

`PA[nosaukums] PA[A daudzums]`

`John                123`

`Ann                 423`

1. In another excel spreadsheet dd i write the name Ann
2. In that same spreadsheet in L12 i write the number.
3. Then i press the button.

For example: i select name Ann and write in number (123); then excel formula subtracts (423-123 = 300) and replaces 423 with 300 in PA[A daudzums].

But if i enter number 423( 423-423=0) then the program wipe the whole row out.

How do i do this. I know i am not that good at English. So if something is not understandable just ask :) I am not that familiar with VBA i don't know how to do this. I have tried normal excel formulas but i cant think of a way for this to work. The last question that i asked i solved with normal in cell formulas but this i don't thing even is possible.

EDIT:
`Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

```
Dim r As Integer
Dim name As String
Dim val As Double

name = Range("L8").Value
val = Range("L12").Value

For r = 1 To [PAtabula].Rows.Count
    If [PAtabula[Uzņēmuma nosaukums]].Rows(r) = name Then
    [PAtabula[Akciju daudzums]].Rows(r).Value = [PAtabula[Akcijudaudzums]].Rows(r).Value - val
    End If
    If [PAtabula[Akciju daudzums]].Rows(r).Value = 0 Then
       [PAtabula].Rows(r).Delete`
    End If
Next r



End Sub`
```

Comment: **Show code**. Show what you've come up with so far. It doesn't matter whether it is working or not. Not everyone speaks/reads/writes english fluently but we all understand **code** or we wouldn't be here. A few lines of **code** can tell us more than several paragraphs; particularly so if english is not your native language.

Comment: Edited the post MAby the problem is there because the excel table has more than 2 columns ( 6)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**edited** to manage no name found

**edited2** to manage qualify filter field as [PAtabula[Uznemuma osaukums]].Column

try this

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
Dim Name As String
Dim val As Double
Dim cell As Range

Name = Range("L8").Value
val = Range("L12").Value

[PAtabula].AutoFilter Field:=[PAtabula[Uznemuma nosaukums]].Column, Criteria1:=Range("L8").Value
If CBool(Application.Subtotal(103, [PAtabula])) Then
    For Each cell In [PAtabula[Akciju daudzums]].SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants, xlNumbers)
        cell.Value = cell.Value - val
    Next cell
End If
[PAtabula].AutoFilter

End Sub
```

as a side note, consider using fully qualified ranges. for instance you may want to use `ActiveSheet.Range("L8")` instead of `Range("L8")` to be sure pointing at the wanted sheet

Comment: I messed something. Now is doesn`t seem to work. It just deletes the empty excel table rows. Shows error at: For Each cell In [PAtabula[Akciju daudzums]].SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants, xlNumbers)
    cell.Value = cell.Value - val

Comment: you must have input a name not in the "Uznemuma nosaukums" column of "PAtabula" table. I edited the code to handle such a case

Comment: I am really bad at this. I am not acting, i am trying but It still doesn`t work. Now it does nothing ;( It should search L8 values in Patabula[Uzņēmuma nosaukums] and L12 (subtract value) in L12.

Comment: seems like "Uznemuma nosaukums" is not the first field of "PAtabula" table as I assumed it was per your example.  See edited code that assures to always filter on "Uznemuma nosaukums" of "PAtabula" table

Comment: Uzņēmuma nosaukums is B4 and akciju daudzums is C4  ; B5(first name) ; C5( FIRST NUMBER) .Still error 424 in the same line ;( Tried maybe formatting but nothing still error

Comment: Error 424 is about missing object or similar. Since the only object involved in the code is a table, I would guess it's a matter of proper table namings (both table name and its fields) or its location with respect to active worksheet when the macro is running. So check for  table namings in the code being as in worksheet table and should it not work again than post you files to have a thorough view of what's where.

Comment: Fixed it. Still is not working. I think it may be bacause it happens in two sheets. So i added: Name = Worksheets("Dati").Range("L8").Value
val = Worksheets("Dati").Range("L12").Value. .......and........ Worksheets("PA").[PAtabula].( everywhere before Patabula). Maby the problem is because Patabula[akciju daudzums] is a formula value ( i added =value for the incell) i don`t know why it is not working ;(

Comment: formulas in Patabula[akciju daudzums] is an issue easy to fix. before updating code please answer the following: 1) does that formula already has a reference to "Dati!L12" ?  2) where's the button you click to have `Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()` run?

Comment: 1) It does not. It has reference to another Excel table in another sheet. 2) It`s the button Pardot shown in the picture :)

Comment: 1) so what should the final result be: 1.1) take the current "value" of each `[Patabula[akciju daudzums]]` cell, subtract `Worksheets("Dati").Range("L12")` from it and leave the result in the cell? 1.1) adjust the current "formula" of each `[Patabula[akciju daudzums]]` cell so as to have `Worksheets("Dati").Range("L12")` subtracted from it and leave the modified formula in the cell? 1.3) other?

Comment: Fixed this.It is working. Sorry for spamming. Thank for helping me :)

Comment: you may want to leave your final code in the question code box for future users reference. moreover if you found my answer useful you may also upvote it. cheers